# Redirect to different paths on PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, phantomjs

I'm looking for a way to redirect on "success" to different paths depending where the authentication process started in the website.

Is there a way to know on the success event where the process started?
Or is there a way to pass some token or any other indication that will return on the callback method?

e.g. if the login started from "www.mysite.com/personal" or "www.mysite.com/public".

i.e. in 'www.mysite.com/personal' user clicks on "google login"

--> 'www.mysite.com/auth/google'

--> PassportJS redirects to google authentication

--> Google redirects back to 'www.mysite.com/auth/google/callback'.

I want to know on "callback" from google last redirect where the user started the process, personal or public?

Comment: You can set a variable in an outer function that defines another function (an inner function) and the inner function will have access to the outer function's variable even though it may be called at a different time in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... 

see my edited question